# Can I track a gameobject Component by its specific ID?

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

I've been working on a system recently that would track changes to an addressable gameobject, similarly to a prefab variant.
The main problem I've run into is that- to my knowledge- I can't track a specific reference to a Component- once the addressable reloads, my reference to the Component directly will be lost.

**I want to be able to get the same component in a gameobject-- ie same GUID, location in the .prefab file, etc, via a system that does not depend on WeakReferences.**

I want to be able to re-find this between addressable loads, during which time I believe a direct component reference will be null.

Can I leverage the ID / GUID system in order to accomplish this? Is there a solution at all, or is this impossible?